# Children count is 0 with observe(DataEventType) in Firebase (Swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some values in my Firebase database to put on some cells, but I get nothing. I printed the amount of children in my reference and realized it said it had 0, but it does have some. I must be doing something wrong. Here's my code in Swift inside viewDidLoad where postCareer is the name of a child inside my Database and postKey a child inside PostCareer. Those are working perfectly.

```
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let comRef = ref.child(postCareer).child(postKey).child("comments")

    comRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snap) in

        print(snap.childrenCount)

        self.newComment.removeAll()

        if snap.childrenCount > 0 {

            for comment in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let object = comment.value as! [String: Any]
                let vCommenter = object["comName"] as! String
                let vComment = object["comDesc"] as! String
                let model = commentStruct(commenter: vCommenter, comment: vComment)
                self.newComment.append(model)

            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

[Here's my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2YcD.png)

```
{
"rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $uid",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $uid"
      }
    },
    "mecIngPosts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
    "usernames": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    },
    "userTestStatus": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Code inside closure:

```
        comRef.observe(DataEventType.value) { (snap) in

        print(snap.childrenCount)
        print(self.postCareer)
        print(self.postKey)
        print(snap)

        self.newComment.removeAll()

        if snap.childrenCount > 0 {

            for comment in snap.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {

                let object = comment.value as! [String: Any]
                let vCommenter = object["comName"] as! String
                let vComment = object["comDesc"] as! String
                print("i don't think")
                print(vCommenter)
                let model = commentStruct(commenter: vCommenter, comment: vComment)
                self.newComment.append(model)

            }

        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: This statement `print(snap.childrenCount)` prints 0 ?

Comment: Yes, it prints 0.

Comment: Please add these statements `print(postCareer)` and `print(postKey)` before `let comRef = ref.child(postCareer).child(postKey).child("comments")` and check if the values are same as you expect or they are different?

Comment: I have also done that, they both work.

Comment: ok another thing that we can try is that instead of `comRef` use `ref` in this statement `comRef.observe...` and check does it get the value of all nodes from firebase db? you can comment other code if you want

Comment: I changed it to ref but my output was "Listener at / failed: permission_denied"

Comment: Are you fetching data from firebase in any other part of your code?

Comment: Yes I am, and they all work perfectly. As a matter of fact, the other children in the randomly generated children on the "mecIngPosts" children are retrieved in another part of my code, and it works perfectly.

Comment: Ok..have you changed the rules for database in firebase?may be have made them custom for your app?

Comment: It works now. Then the problem is on my rules. I'll add them to my post.

Comment: Ok.. good work. :)

Comment: Done. What do you think I should change?

Comment: I just tried it again and even with public rules, it doesn't work with "comRef". The problem is not the rules then.

Comment: Ok..One more thing that we can try is to remove `.child("comments")` and then run the above code and please comment the lines inside the closure and only add this statement `print(snap)` and see what it prints?

Comment: I'll add what I wrote inside the closure. This is what it printed:
0
mecIngPosts
L5zPoCG42MNANDB3hnF
Snap (L5zPoCG42MNANDB3hnF) <null>